# Why does parseInt() in map() only work for first item in an array?

Tags: node.js, functional-programming, parseint

Output from Node.js repl:

```
> ["1", "2"].map(i => parseInt(i)); // correct
[ 1, 2 ]
> ["1", "2"].map(i => i); // correct
[ '1', '2' ]
> ["1", "2"].map(parseInt); // what is causing the NaN?
[ 1, NaN ]
```

Should not the last result be `[1, 2]`?

Version:

```
$ node --version
v6.9.1
```

Comment: What is the signature of parseInt? What gets passed to map callbacks? Do you see the issue? I believe you're providing an invalid radix if I remember right.